# How to repeat a Javascript program

Tags: javascript

I want to repeat a javascript and I cannot find any way to do it I want to repeat the statement infinite number of times till now i was copying it and pasting it again and again can any body help me out to do so the statement or command I want to repeat is

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

can any body call me how to repeat it without pasting it again and again

Comment: You need to learn about loops.

Comment: tell me the loop which can repeat it infinite number of time

Comment: You heavily need to learn about coding in general if you don't know how to loop (also infinite times).

Comment: I know but its not working the loop is for (;;window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));

Answer (score 0):

You can loop infinitely:

```
for (;;window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));
```

but this will very likely lead to some "[tab] is not responding" shenanigans, so I'd just listen for a scroll event:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
};
```